# Sugar coated pecans without turning amber

Tags: sugar, candy, nuts

I had an old Aunt who used to make the best sugar coated pecans.

I have tried to replicate the recipe but where hers were a snowy white colour mine turn out caramel looking.

How do I do this and have them stay white?

Comment: Can you describe what the color/texture looked like in more detail?  Were they coated in sugar / powdered sugar?

Comment: Are you asking for a recipe or a techinque? Can you tell us how you're doing it currently?

Comment: The only way that I know to end up with them white is to add more sugar at the end (after any cooking) so it’s glued on, but not melted

Comment: Welcome to SA!  You'll get much more useful answers from folks if you can describe your current confection recipe/process.

Answer (score 1):

As you have not described the recipe it isn't possible to pinpoint what you may be doing to cause the caramelization.

However, by first whipping up some egg whites, then mixing through the nuts, and finally drenching with sugar before roasting/baking in a cool-slow oven (about 250F/120C), they should remain white.

This is because sugar caramelizes at about 338F/170C. So as long as the oven is not too hot then it should not caramelize before the nuts are roasted.